# Prove that the following statements are equivalent.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nilpotence, characteristic-polynomial

Let A be a nxn Matrix whose characteristic polynomial XA can be decomposed into a product of linear factors.

1. A^n = 0
2. A is nilpotent
3. 0 is the only Eigenvalue of A.

I did the steps 1) => 2) but I'm stuck on 2) => 3) and 3) => 1).
I'm unsure how to use the fact that the characteristic Polynomial can be decomposed into a product of linear factors.
Isn't the characteristic polynomial in 3) just equal to the determinant of A since the only eigenvalue is 0?

1. => 2) is trivial since k = n with A^k = 0 so A is nilpotent
2. => 3):
   $$A^k = 0$$
   $$Av = \lambda v$$
   $$A^kv = \lambda A^{k-1}v$$
   $$\lambda A^{k-1}v = 0$$

Comment: Hint : if $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$ what is the minimal polynom of $A$ ? (it is of order $n$ and it divides any cancelling polynom of $A$).

Comment: Can't all polynomials be decomposed into a product of linear factors?

Comment: For $(2)\Rightarrow(3)$, if $A^{k}=0$ for some $k$ (definition of nillpotent), then what polynomial does the minimal polynomial of $A$ divide?

Comment: If $A v = \lambda v$, what can you say about $A^2  v$, then $A^3 v$, ... ?

Comment: for $3\implies 1$: eigenvalues are zeros of the characteristic polynomial. If the polynomial has only linear factors and its only zero is $0$, what does that polynomial look like?